# Assigning priorities to wxPython events

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Is there anyway to assign priorities to specific wxPython event?

I periodically call a method using a timer after starting my GUI. But I want to be able to get out of this method as soon as the user presses a button. Is this possible without having a worker thread?

Comment: I doubt this is possible without a separate thread.  Keyboard events are probably handled at some point in wx's mainloop which means you need to return program control back to the mainloop (from your function) for your events to be handled.

Comment: What about wx.Yield(). I'm not exactly sure what it does but it seems to return control back to the mainloop.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with `wx` to say.  I know that in `Tkinter`, you could do something like `widget.update_idletasks()`.  But that doesn't get the keyboard event right away -- that gets it when your program gets to `update_idletasks()`.

Comment: According to http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/916779-button-label-change-evt_button-wxpython , `wx.Yield()` is equivalent to `tkinter.update_idletasks()`.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of. The events are added to the event queue in the order they are received. You might be able to do this with a thread where the process is running in the thread and you kill it. You might try asking on the wxPython mailing list for other ideas though. A couple of the core developers are there and they might have some insights for you.